# DIVs are not visible? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with divs that I create with a simple function. I can see them in the console that they have color and are positioned well. However they are not displayed on the browser?

```
function CreateDivs(){
        var dfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var divNumbers = 5;
        var i = 0;
        var angle = 0;
        for(i=0; i < divNumbers; i++){
            x = 100 * Math.cos(angle) + 200;
            y = 100 * Math.sin(angle) + 200;

            var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.left = x + "px";
                div.style.right = y + "px";
                div.style.borderColor = rndColor();
                div.style.backgroundColor = rndColor();

                dfrag.appendChild(div);
                }
                divWrapper.appendChild(dfrag);
            }
```

I use a simple function rndColor();

```
 var createButton = document.getElementById("div-generator");
 var divWrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
```

[A working JsBin here.](http://jsbin.com/AlibUwA/1/edit)

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle to show your problem?

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: Any errors on the console? May be a scoping problem with `divWrapper`, e.g.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this! http://jsbin.com/AlibUwA/1/edit

Comment: @HenryLynx Your code is working fine. Just give some height or give a bg-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your divs are "empty".

You can

- set a content, so the <div> gains a height ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MujVM/1/)):

  ```
  div.innerHTML = "A";
  ```
- set a height instead of providing a content ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MujVM/)):

  ```
  div.style.height = "10px";
  ```
- combine the latter approach with CSS classes ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MujVM/2/)):

  ```
  div.className = "my-div";

  .my-div {
    min-height: 20px;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your div has no width and height.

set the width and height to your div.

```
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
```